# Check if other node has same child node value

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to implement validation rule that will check when new `$resvs` is created if any other `$resvs` contains the same `eventKey` (which is a child node of that object) as the already existing `reservations` nodes.

The following code is not working, but can't come up with anything better now:

```
"reservations": {        
  "$resvs": {        
    ".write": "!data.exists() || newData.child('eventKey').val() == root.child('reservations/$resvs/eventKey').val()"
  }
}
```

edit:

```
firebase.database().ref('/reservations').push({
        name: name,
        number: number,
        email: email,
        start: start,
        end: end,           
        scheduleId: scheduleId,
        scheduleName: scheduleName,
        eventKey: eventKey,
        placeId: placeId
    }).then(function(){
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents'); //confirmaton first? TODO
    }).catch(function(error){
      alert('err');
    });
```

Comment: If the event key is the unique identifier, why not store the reservations keyed by them, instead of putting them in a field? There's no way to do a wildcard like you want here in security rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem, i recomand you change the database structure a little bit. Instead of using the `event key` as a field, try to store the reservation data directly under the `event key`. In this way you can double check, once in code and once using security rules. If you want to check in your code, just add a listener on the `reservations` node and use `exists()` method on the dataSnapshot object. In the same manner use the security rules, because with your actual database structure it's impossible to use wildcards in the way you want.

Your database new structure should look like this:

```
Firebase-root
     |
     --- reservations
              |
              --- eventKey1
              |      |
              |      --- //event1 details
              |
              --- eventKey2
                     |
                     --- //event2 details
```

But remember, this will work only and only if the the event key are `unique`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: It seems like the most viable solution. I updated my question with actual code for creating reservation. How should I modify it to use `eventKey` as a parent key?

Comment: Yes, new data structure makes perfect sense. What I still struggle with is code implementation - I think about adding `eventKey` at the end of `ref` url so it would store it there.

Comment: It's an option. Because it's unique, you can also use only the eventKey. As you wish.